# SQL Server : How to Select Sum Amount Spent for the Most Expensive Item by a Customer - Northwind DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

Actually question tells all; Lots of customers has many orders with for many items; I'm trying to display the total amount spent for the most expensive item ordered by that customers through the all orders given by that customer. I'm using Northwind DB and tables like Customers, Orders, Order Details, Products. I've the query below, I've tried to limit it by an aggregate function but SQL does not allow it on where clause. Any help?

```
select 
    p.ProductName,
    c.ContactName,
    od.ProductID,
    MAX(od.UnitPrice)
    SUM(od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity) as Total
from 
    Customers c
join 
    Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
join 
    [Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
join 
    Products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
where 
    c.CustomerID in 
group by 
    c.ContactName, p.ProductName, od.Quantity, od.ProductID
order by 
    MAX(od.UnitPrice) desc
```

Comment: So you'd like 1 row per `ContactName`, and that row would be the highest `UnitPrice` that person has?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to solve this is by using a window function to get the highest priced product.  The following query uses `row_number()` for this purpose:

```
select p.ProductName, c.ContactName, od.ProductID,
       MAX(od.UnitPrice)
       SUM(od.UnitPrice*od.Quantity) as Total
from Customers c join 
     (select od.*, o.CustomerId,
             row_number() over (partition by o.CustomerId
                                order by od.UnitPrice desc) as seqnum
      from [Order Details] od join
           Orders o
           on od.OrderId = o.OrderId
     ) od
     on od.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and seqnum = 1 join 
     Products p
     on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
group by c.ContactName, p.ProductName, od.ProductID
order by MAX(od.UnitPrice) desc;
```

Note that the `join`s have been rearranged a bit.  You need the customer id to define the highest priced product in the subquery, so the subquery has the join to `orders`.  You don't need the join in the outer query.

Comment: Thx for the answer but SSMS gives syntax error on "od" after paranthesis on line 11

Comment: @user1599986 . . . I see no obvious syntax problem.  SQL Server requires table aliases on subqueries so this is standard syntax.